# How to make two objects inversely orbiting a point do so in a curve? Unity, C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this function attached to a sphere and in inverse one attached to another. They are rigged to emit a trail and the game object they are orbiting around is a sphere which is locked at 0,0,0. This is my code so far :

```
  float t = 0;
    float speed;
    float width;
    float height;
    int cat = 0;
    public GameObject orbit; //the object to orbit

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 2;
        width = 5;
        height = 2;
        InvokeRepeating("test", .001f, .009f);
    }

    void test()
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime * speed;

        Vector3 orbitv = orbit.transform.position;
        float inc = .0000000001f;

        inc += inc + t;
        float angmom = .00001f;
        angmom = angmom + t;

        float x = orbitv.x + Mathf.Cos(t);
        float z = orbitv.z + inc; //+ (Mathf.Cos(t)*Mathf.Sin(t));
        float y = orbitv.y + Mathf.Sin(t);

        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);



    }}
```

Which does this:[image]

Instead of moving in the z direction exclusively, I'd like them to continue their current rotation, but in a circle around the sphere at 0,0,0 while staying at the same y level. Anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

Edit: This is what I'm trying to do: [image]

Comment: I suggest you start by breaking this down into simpler problems. This will help you write a question which is easier for others to understand and easier for us to answer. All I understand is that you have two objects orbiting around a sphere. Simplify this to **one** object orbiting a sphere. What do you want that object to do exactly, other than just orbit?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a dna helix in a ring shape, right now, it creates the helix trail but only in the z direction and I'm not sure how to make it circular.

Comment: What do you mean by "it creates the helix trail but only in the z direction and I'm not sure how to make it circular." By definition, a helix is circular. If it isn't circular then you don't have a helix. Do you mean that you are getting a straight line?

Comment: What is the angle of your camera relative to the helix? Are you viewing it straight on? What if you move your camera to a different angle?

Comment: "I'd like them to continue their current rotation, but in a circle around the sphere at 0,0,0 while staying at the same y level. " If you don't want to change the `z` coordinate of your objects, then remove the line which increments it. This will keep your objects moving in a circle in a plain instead of in a helix shape.

Comment: The camera angle is going to be moving, I'd like it inline with the z axis, So that the helix circles the sphere in the middle, imagine it like a planetary orbit, that's what I'm going for.

Comment: A planetary orbit isn't a helix. And I still don't understand how what you want differs from what you are currently getting. I'm more than willing to help but I need more information to clarify what you want.

Comment: What I'm trying to do in the simplst terms is to have two objects move creating a trail that is a helix which is moving in a circle around the center sphere.

Comment: I've edited my original post with a paint picture of what I'm trying to do, to try and clarify it.

Comment: What does your current code do that you don't want? Or what doesn't it do that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code I cooked up for you.
All the movement is achieved with basic trigonometric functions and some easy vector math.

To tackle problems like these, try to break things down like I did with dividing the movement into circular/up-down & sideways. This lets you create the ring effect.

Adding more intertwined waves should be trivial by changing the phase of the oscillations and adding more trails.

```
public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour {

    float t = 0;
    public float speed;
    public float width;
    public float height;
    public float radius;
    int cat = 0;
    public GameObject center; //the object to orbit
    public Vector3 offset;

    void Update()
    {
        t = Time.time * speed;
        OrbitAround();
        AddSideways();
    }

    void OrbitAround()
    {
        float x = radius * Mathf.Cos(t);
        float y = Mathf.Sin(offset.y * t);
        float z = radius * Mathf.Sin(t);

        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    void AddSideways()
    {
        float x = Mathf.Cos(offset.x * t);
        Vector3 dir = transform.position - center.transform.position;
        transform.position += dir.normalized * x;

    }
}
```

It should give you a trail like this:
[image]

You can play around with the `Vec3 offset` which changes the frequency of the oscillations and essentially lets you choose the number of rings.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to accomplish, thanks for the help!